# Backbone: My model doesn't pass the id. Its a commenting system. I am trying to post the created comment, to the backend

Tags: backbone.js, mongoose, backbone-views, backbone-events, backbone.js-collections

Backbone:I'm trying to create a commenting system. My model doesn't pass the id.  I am trying to post the created comment, to the backend. 
When trying to create, passing id value as option, but it never gets passed to the options in collection.
Part of the code, is as below:

this.collection.create({body: commentVal},({wait: true,id : _id}));

```
/* This is comments Model */
define([
  'backbone'
], function(Backbone){
  var CommentModel = Backbone.Model.extend({  
    defaults: {
        body: " "
    } 
  });
  //Returns the model for the module
  return CommentModel;
});

/* This is comments collection */

define([
  'jquery',
  'backbone',
  '../models/comment'
], function($, Backbone, CommentModel){

  var CommentCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: CommentModel,

    url: function() {
      var urlRoot = '/api/v1/comment';
      return urlRoot + '/' + this.id;
    },

    initialize: function(attrs,options){
     this.id = options.id;
    }

  });

  return CommentCollection;  // We should never return collection instantiated.
});
```

Comment: When you create something there is no ID.  No ID indicates you want to create or post something.  He backend should be the one providing an ID possibly a DB.  So the backend should apply the ID then send back the posted model bound with an ID.

Answer (score 0):

This way should work for you:

```
var comments = new CommentCollection([],{id:_id });
            comments.fetch({
                success: function(){},
                error: function(){}
});
```